# How to export the data in CSV format of Redshift cluster using psql

Tags: csv, amazon-redshift, psql

Below is what I tried in Linux Shell Script.

```
psql "dbname=dbname host=host user=user password=password port=port" -A -F ',' -c "select * from table" > /path/sql_output.csv
```

Though above command gives me the output in csv format, its not a good solution. Because this approache will generate broken CSV files in many cases such as when fields contain quotes and commas.

And I tried with another way by using COPY command but got an error.

```
psql "dbname=dbname host=host user=user password=password port=port" -c "COPY ( SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY id limit 10 ) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER " > /path/sql_output.csv
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Note: I'm not a super user here.

Comment: Postgres or Redhift? Those are two very different things. Also what **is** the error you got?

Comment: This is for Redshift. ERROR:  syntax error at or near "(".

Comment: [As documented in the manual](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) Redshift does not support a query for the `copy` command

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Any alternative methods ?

Comment: Just create a (temporary) table first and then use that for the `COPY`.

Answer (score 0):

To export data into a local file you can do it using the psql client by redirecting the output to a file using `\o file_redirect.csv`:

```
\a    -- aligned/unaligned
\f ,  -- field separator , (default is |)
\t    -- show rows on/off
\o /tmp/sql_output.csv -- output file
```

Then:

```
select * from table;
```